# Intuition for the difference between normalisation and log-scaling

Tags: normalization

So I understand that turning features into log space can be useful if one wants to represent relative differences, whereas linear features show absolute differences.

As I understand it though, normalisation achieves a kind of relativity as well (i.e. normalising a picture still leaves the shapes and content intact) and the features are much closer together in the feature space, which enables more efficient learning.

My question is simply what the difference is between these two feature transformations, or if there is not much of a major difference. Additionally, are there any good resources (ML or statistics or otherwise) that explain the rationale behind choosing these scalings and transformations?

This is from someone who is doing some work on ML but isn’t an expert on statistics. I get the gist of these ideas separately, but I’m unclear on whether it makes sense to combine the two together and how they differ from each other.

Comment: Normalisation doesn't mean the same thing across quantitative fields and not even within the spectrum from statistics to machine learning. So, precise definitions or examples would help.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing means, essentially, trying to make a distribution normal. It doesn't leave shapes intact, it doesn't necessarily bring features closer together and, since it changes the scale, it's not clear if "closer together" has a real meaning.  In my opinion it is done far too often and we should often be changing our method rather than changing the data.

Sometimes taking the log of a variable will make it look more normal. Sometimes not. Taking the log of a variable is useful if the variable makes more sense in multiplicative terms than additive ones. This is often useful for variables that involve money, because we tend to think of money that way.  The difference between a \$10,000 house and an \$15,000 is huge; the difference between a \$1,000,000 house and a \$1,005,000 house is tiny.

Comment: In machine learning, normalise seems often to mean just some kind of linear scaling to approximately similar units such as (value $-$ mean) / SD or (value $-$ min) / (max $-$ min). People who think of themselves as working within statistics (rather than in machine learning) tend to think of that as standardizing. (Working definition: As in the original question, you're in machine learning if you think that ML means machine learning. You're in statistics if you think ML means maximum likelihood.)

Comment: Thanks @NickCox . Maybe the question should be edited to reflect this difference in definitions?

Comment: Indeed and I've already suggested that to the OP. I don't think it's for anyone else to do.